# How to remove deprecated files from new version of package?

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

I'm building a new version of my own debian package, there is something was changed and some files now should be removed (for example old upstart scripts which shouldn't be executed more). I just removed those files from debian package and looks like they are missing in resulting deb-file. Also if I'm installing new version on a clean machine everything is fine, but when I upgrading extising installation removed files are still there and present in a list of owned by package files: `dpkg -L <package name>` (or at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package-name>.list` which is obviously the same thing).

So my question is: how should I remove those files correctly?

Comment: Are these all `conffiles`?  As far as I know anything that isn't a `conffile`, but I may be wrong.

Comment: As I can see in the docs: `dh_installdeb(1) automatically flags any files under the /etc directory as conffiles`, it's upstart scripts (at least only them are bothering me right now) so they are placed in `/etc/init.d/` and I think yes, they should be marked as conffiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that when it comes to conffiles the user of the package is intended to resolve the cleanup of cruft themselves.

I am not sure about the specifics from a Debian packaging Policy perspective, but if you need remove, relocate, or modify a conffile in an upgrade, you can handle it in one of the various preinst/postinst hook scripts.  I know I have seen this done to a certain degree existing packages.

Here is an example from the the grub postinst `/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-common.postinst` script.  The call to [dpkg-maintscript-helper rm_conffile](http://man.cx/dpkg-maintscript-helper) will remove the configuration under certain conditions.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Automatically added by dh_installdeb
dpkg-maintscript-helper rm_conffile /etc/grub.d/10_freebsd 2.00-14~ -- "$@"
# End automatically added section
# Automatically added by dh_installdeb
dpkg-maintscript-helper rm_conffile /etc/grub.d/10_hurd 2.00-14~ -- "$@"
# End automatically added section
```